# IOS16 portrait rotate issue

Tags: rotation, screen, portrait, ios16

Hi I wanna fix the bug which occur in IOS16 for rotation screen
I refer to this article, but it's still not working....

BTW we used the Object-c instead of Swift

[Reference](https://medium.com/@roperluo.me/ios16-xcode14-adaptation-525eaa1ad7b4)

```
    UIWindowScene  *windowScene  = ( UIWindowScene  *)[[[ UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes]      allObjects].firstObject;
     UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS  *perference  = [[ UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS alloc]  init];
    perference.interfaceOrientations  =  1  < deviceOrientation;
    [windowScene requestGeometryUpdateWithPreferences:perference errorHandler: ^( NSError  * _Nonnull error) {
         NSLog(@ "error--%@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

```
 self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
```

before requesting the geometry update fixes it for me.

Comment: Could you please provide the obj-c implementation as i'm from RN background and new to obj-c/swift including the one you mentioned above. Kindly advise as i'm a need to fix this as the first this year as there is no one around at my end to help me out.