# How to implement a solution to change the orientation to landscape and vice versa

Tags: objective-c, rotation, portrait, ios16

I'm from RN background and pretty new to Objective-C/Swift. Though it is RN project, but there are lot of implementation written by previous engineers in Objective-C/Swift. This particular implementation was written in Objective-C which is to lock the screen in both portrait and landscape. But the problem here the landscape mode doesn't work for iOS 16.

Upon reading through the docs I discover that iOS 16 uses requestGeometryUpdateWithPreferences which our code need to be updated based on that. I've been looking around for the solution in Objective-C and I found this [partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598180/ios16-portrait-rotate-issue/74642176#74642176) and the [solution in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124396/is-force-view-controller-orientation-working-in-ios-16-beta/75064745#75064745).

I thought of using the partial solution above with the my little update to define the deviceOrientation. But I know it won't work and is incorrect with the code below. What can I try next?

```
  UIInterfaceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    
    UIWindowScene  *windowScene  = ( UIWindowScene  *)[[[ UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes]      allObjects].firstObject;
    
         UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS  *perference  = [[ UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS alloc]  init];
        perference.interfaceOrientations  =  1  < deviceOrientation;
    
      
        [windowScene requestGeometryUpdateWithPreferences:perference errorHandler: ^( NSError  * _Nonnull error) {
             NSLog(@ "error--%@", error);
        }];
```